# How can I start vifm with horizontal splitting

Tags: vifm

Is it possible to start `vifm` with horizontal splitting?
I launch `tmux` with several panes. I want to have `vifm` in one of them, but it doesn't look nice in vertical split mode and I always have to change split mode manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put [`:split`](http://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml#vifm-%3Asplit) command to your [`~/.vifm/vifmrc`](http://wiki.vifm.info/index.php?title=Configuration_model#Configuration_files) file.

Command description:

> :sp[lit] -  switch to a two window horizontal view.

You can do the same with pretty much any other command-line command. Say, since we're talking about layout here, it could be [`:vsplit`](http://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml#vifm-%3Avsplit) or [`:only`](http://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml#vifm-%3Aonly).